# detect if a given environment variable(only part of the environment variable name is given) is set in bash

Tags: linux, bash, pattern-matching

I want to do things like following in bash:

```
if [ "${AA_BB_*}" ] ; then
    echo "I am in"
fi
```

And "AA__BB" is just a patter. So no matter I have set "AA_BB_1" or "AA_BB_X" in my environment, this script will print "I am in"

How can I achieve that? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close: `${!AA_BB_*}` will expand to the list of variable names that match `AA_BB_*`.

```
if [ "${!AA_BB_*}" ]; then
```

However, note that this will match against *all* shell variables, not just those whose `export` attribute is set. If you really want to check specifically against environment variables, you'll have to `grep` the output of `env`:

```
if env | grep -q 'AA_BB_*'; then
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use env to list the variables, awk to select only variable name and grep to match the pattern:

`if (env | awk -F= '{print $1}' | grep -q "AA_BB_*"); then  echo 'I am in' ;fi`